# jQuery Tools UI Tab Won't Locate Panes

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I've referenced the jQuery UI TOOLS source in my HTML file, and I then proceed to create an unordered list like so:

```
<ul class="tabs">  
    <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">blah 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I then have my content or panes like so:

```
<div class="panes">
    <div>
        <div id="body">Random body inside a pane</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="body">More stuff</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So to then activate these tabs, in my JS file I call:

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
```

This should activate the tabs and organise them into their panes. However, all the content stays in one block, and the tabs have no functionality. I can see no flaw in my code and have no idea what the problem is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/ your markup should look like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">blah</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#tab-2">blah 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panes">
        <div>
            <div id="tab-1">Random body inside a pane</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="tab-2">More stuff</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/ZZeYD/1/

Comment: If you are using that library then your code looks fine, make sure your JavaScript's are loaded in correct order (jquery first and then the libraries and at the end your custom js) also worth wrapping your JavaScript inside $(function() {    ....     });

Comment: I got it! I gave the child `div`'s an id, and it worked for some reason. :)

Comment: By the way just noticed, ids should always be unique and both of your tab content divs had the same id that should have been the problem, if you remove both their ids it should also work